# How to use mixin to ignore a field when using ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, mixins

```
class Apple{

@JsonProperty("colour")
public String colour;

@JsonProperty("dummy_params")
public DummyParams dummyParams;

}
```

```
public abstract class AppleMixin{

    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty("dummy_params")
    public DummyParams dummyParams;

}
```

I am trying to ignore dummyParams field when using ObjectMapper

```
class Tester{
  public static void main(){
  Apple app = new Apple();
  app.setColor("red");
  app.setDummyParams(new DummyParams("1","2"));

  ObjectMapper objecMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  objecMapper.addMixIn(Apple.class, AppleMixin.class);
  String result = objecMapper.writeValueAsString(exec);
  }
}
```

I am using com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

Expected Result : {"colour": "red"}

Actual Result : {"colour":"red", "dummyParams":{"dummyOne" :1,"dummyTwo":2}}

The mixin is not working.Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` on the mixin class or provide an appropriate `abstract` getter and annotate that with the `JsonIgnore`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for your reply. I tried the both way added a getter and setter with `@JsonIgnore` and used `@JsonIgnoreProperties` on class level. Still the "dummyParams" field is not removing from the object.

Comment: Instead of creating mixin I added a access value `@JsonProperty(value = "dummy_params", access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)` to dummyParams field of apple class. Problem solved!